# How to dynamically add a link to a parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, hyperlink

In my snippet below you will see a blue and red block. The red is indicating that a specific duty is not completed. What I am trying to do for these unfinished duties is dynamically make its outer div (one of these `#account-unfinished-package, #account-unfinished-logo`) to act as a link.

I am unsure of how to do this dynamically, since the duties (blocks) will be changing from unfinished/finished. I do not want the finished blocks to have links, or else I would just add it to the html.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can make the outer divs for the unfinished blocks act as a link dynamically?

[Here is a jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/2jgypcxo/)

```js
var unfinishedPack = 1;
var unfinishedLogo = 0;
if (unfinishedPack == 0) {
  $('#account-unfinished-package').addClass('red');
  $('#unfinished-title-package').html('Product package needs setup.');
  $('#unfinished-img-package').html("<img src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/retain-static/images/realestate/error-circle.png' class='unfinished-img' alt='Package Needs Setup'>");
}
else if (unfinishedPack > 0) {
  $('#account-unfinished-package').addClass('blue');
  $('#unfinished-title-package').html('Product Package Setup Complete!');
  $('#unfinished-img-package').html("<img src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/retain-static/images/realestate/checkmark-circle-white.png' class='unfinished-img' alt='Package Complete'>");
}

if (unfinishedLogo == 0) {
  $('#account-unfinished-logo').addClass('red');
  $('#unfinished-title-logo').html('Company logo needs added. <a href="#">Click to add</a>');
  $('#unfinished-img-logo').html("<img src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/retain-static/images/realestate/error-circle.png' class='unfinished-img' alt='Logo Needs Added'>");
}
else if (unfinishedPack > 0) {
  $('#account-unfinished-logo').addClass('blue');
  $('#unfinished-title-logo').html('Account Logos Complete!');
  $('#unfinished-img-logo').html("<img src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/retain-static/images/realestate/checkmark-circle-white.png' class='unfinished-img' alt='Logo Complete'>");
}
```

```css
#account-unfinished {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    /*color: #D8000C;*/
    /*background: #FFBABA;*/
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: none;
}
#account-unfinished.block {
    display: block;
}
#account-unfinished-package, #account-unfinished-logo {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#account-unfinished-package.red, #account-unfinished-logo.red {
    background: #D8000C;
    height: 100%;
}
#account-unfinished-package.blue, #account-unfinished-logo.blue {
    background: #09afdf;
    height: 100%;
}
.account-unfinished-inner {
    padding: 15px;
}
.account-unfinished-title {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    text-align: center;
}
.account-unfinished-title a {
    color: #FFF;
}
#unfinished-img-package, #unfinished-img-logo {
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.unfinished-img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="account-unfinished-package">
  <div class="account-unfinished-inner">
    <p class="account-unfinished-title" id="unfinished-title-package"></p>
    <div id="unfinished-img-package"></div>
  </div>
</div><div id="account-unfinished-logo">
  <div class="account-unfinished-inner">
    <p class="account-unfinished-title" id="unfinished-title-logo"></p>
    <div id="unfinished-img-logo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So essentially you want to wrap the "unfinished" blocks with an `<a>` element, and when they're "finished" - unwrap them?

Comment: @Catalyst Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `wrapInner` function:

```
if (unfinishedLogo == 0) {
  $('#account-unfinished-logo').addClass('red');
  $('#account-unfinished-logo').wrapInner('<a href="https://google.com"></a>');
  $('#unfinished-title-logo').html('Company logo needs added. <a href="#">Click to add</a>');
  $('#unfinished-img-logo').html("<img src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/retain-static/images/realestate/error-circle.png' class='unfinished-img' alt='Logo Needs Added'>");
}
else if (unfinishedPack > 0) {
  $('#account-unfinished-logo').addClass('blue');
  $('#unfinished-title-logo').html('Account Logos Complete!');
  $('#unfinished-img-logo').html("<img src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/retain-static/images/realestate/checkmark-circle-white.png' class='unfinished-img' alt='Logo Complete'>");
}
```

I made you a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4mLjdee5/

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why the logo box disappears when I changed the finished variables? ... like this ...`var unfinishedPack = 0;
var unfinishedLogo = 1;`1

Comment: Yes, you have a copy pasta mistake. Check my update, I made it in the above code as well -- `else if (unfinishedPack > 0) {` should be  `(unfinishedLogo > 0) {` https://jsfiddle.net/4mLjdee5/1/

Comment: Thanks... didn't see that mistake. I appreciate the help!